# Maui how set autoscaling for font

Tags: c#, maui

I can see label have property `FontAutoScalingEnabled`

I tried to set it with different value and combination for other properties:

```
FontSize
MaxLines
HeightRequest
WidthRequest
```

My label is inside grid. I tried also to set heigh and width to int values insted of use `*`

Unfortunetly it never change size the font when don't fit in label.
How to use it?

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?view=net-maui-7.0#disable-font-auto-scaling).  This property doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Maui does not have font-auto-sizing.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Any advice on how to adapt the interface to different screen sizes?

Comment: You can set FontSize in c# (code behind), based on screen size. Unfortunately, for now, its up to you to make your best guess. I'll write a library that helps with sizing, but may be two or three months before I do that. (Requires custom code on each platform (ios etc) to measure the text, to do it accurately.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same use case.

What I did is creating a converter that implements IValueConverter.

```
public class LengthToFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string text)
        {
            return text.Length switch
            {
                > 20 => 12,
                > 10 => 14,
                _ => 16
            };
        }
        return 16;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It simply check the length of the string of the text and adjust the font size.
You can customize your own checking length / font size in the return switch statement.

Then, in your xaml, you can add this kind of code:

```
<maui:ReactiveContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:LengthToFontSizeConverter x:Key="LengthToFontSizeConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</maui:ReactiveContentPage.Resources>
```

Do not forget to add you own ***xmln:converters="clr-namespace:..."***

Finally, on any label or other kind of stuff that use a FontSize:

```
<Label 
    Text="{Binding Name}" 
    FontSize="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource LengthToFontSizeConverter}}" />
```

Hope it can help someone.
If you found a better solution, please share it ! :)

FYI: I'm using ReactiveUI.Maui, that why I have ***maui:ReactiveContentPage.Resources...*** But you can use ***<ContentPage.Resources>...***

Answer (score -1):

> My label is inside grid. I tried also to set heigh and width to int values insted of use `*`. Unfortunetly it never change size the font when don't fit in label. How to use it?

You can set Height and Width to `Auto` instead of `Absolute` or `Star`. And then set FontSize of Label:

```
<Grid>                
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>                    
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                    
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                    
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>                
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                    
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>                    
        <ColumnDefinition />                
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
    <Label Text="Row 0, Column 0"                       
           FontSize="Large"                       
           BackgroundColor="BurlyWood"/>                
    <Label Grid.Column="1"                       
           Text="Row 0, Column 1 xx"                       
           FontSize="Large"                       
           BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>                
    <Label Grid.Row="1"                       
           Text="Row 1"                       
           FontSize="50"                       
           BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>                
    <Label Grid.Row="2"                       
           Text="Row 2, Column 0"                       
           FontSize="Large"                       
           BackgroundColor="BurlyWood"/>            
</Grid>
```

I tested the code, and it works well. For more information, you can refer to [Rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0#rows-and-columns) by official.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the behavior I expect. The subtitles are not reduced, only the interface is extended, and if there is not enough space, the subtitle is broken into several lines.

Comment: It seems that you can only change the font size manually.